# YouSendIt Alternative?

Tags: uploading

Looking for a *reasonably* priced alternative to YouSendIt's exorbitant pricing for an embedded, unbranded (i.e. no "Uploads by SomeCompany" or at the very least, discrete, subtle co-branding) file upload solution for my client's print shop Website.  To do what we want to do with YouSendIt, we're looking at a corporate account of $995 USD *plus* $29.99 USD monthly fee, that is only sold pro-rated, so you have to buy the entire year's worth.  To me, this is just unacceptable considering the commodity pricing of storage and bandwidth nowadays.

For data, we're looking at roughly 10MB per upload, with perhaps 250-1000 uploads per month, with transient data storage of no more than 30 days (and more than likely 1-2 business days) for a total of 10 GB transfer (upload) and 10 GB transfer (download, to the print shop) at the very max each month.

Any ideas?  Everything I've found through searching seems to be geared more towards personal file sharing and not for embedding into Websites.

Comment: Are you sending to the client or the client sending to you?

Comment: My client (the print shop), will be receiving file uploads on their site (theprintshop.com), from _their_ customers (PDFs, TIFFs, etc. for printing).  I'm just the Web Designer.

Answer (score 2):

We, a London based Advertising Agency, are using a Danish based service called [Filecamp](http://filecamp.com) to share files and collaborate with our clients.

I'm quite sure it comes with unlimited users and bandwidth, it's brandable ... and I think it´s well worth the small monthly fee. Our designers love it and our clients love it!

We actually used combination of YouSendit, Dropbox and our own FTP server before, but now has Filecamp taken over our entire File-sending and File-receiving process.

Answer (score 1):

We recently looked at several solutions for this, including YouSendIt, [iExtranet](http://en.oodrive-collaboration.com/our-solutions/iextranet-solution/overview-iextranet.html), [ShareFile](http://www.sharefile.com/), [Dropsend](http://www.dropsend.com/), and [TransferBigFiles](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/).

For us, the best mix of features, performance, and cost, was [ShareFile](http://www.sharefile.com/). It's easy to use, brandable, has unlimited clients, is reasonably priced, and transfers were quick (we're based in Asia, so not all services have good performance here).

Answer (score 0):

You could mount your client's Amazon S3 account as a filesystem in userspace ([Windows](http://wins3fs.codeplex.com/)/[Linux](http://shahidz.com/mounting-amazon-s3-bucket-to-a-local-linux-file-system/)) and upload the files to that location - likely the cheapest and most reliable in-house solution if you are OK to code something up.

Comment: Really would like to avoid coding as the embedded HTML code approach is simple/easy to maintain/maintenance-free for anyone else who may take over the site.